# Getting element type is invalid error when trying to populate cards with JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I know this error has been posted many times, but none of the fixes worked for me. And i have been stuck with it for a week now...

I am learning react in my spare time, and i want to make a webpage that takes a json object, iterates through it to populate cards, and returns the cards. This is made in a component that i import into the main page. Here is the error:

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `Dashboard`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { CardHeader, Card } from "@material-ui/core";
import render from "react-dom";


export default function CardComponent() {
  let bedpressJSONObject = {
    bedpress: {
      "0": {
        bedriftsnavn: "hei",
        dato: "24.12.12",
        info: "asdasdsadas"
      },
      "1": {
        bedriftsnavn: "på",
        dato: "14.05.22",
        info: "gfdsgdfsbvfbvsrgf"
      },
      "2": {
        bedriftsnavn: "dei",
        dato: "15.2.12",
        info: "243wresdfvxzgbtr"
      }
    }
  };

  let cardList = [];
  Object.keys(bedpressJSONObject.bedpress).forEach(index => {
    let card = bedpressJSONObject.bedpress[index];
    console.log(card.dato)
    cardList.push(
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          title={card.bedriftsnavn}
          subtitle={card.dato}
          actAsExpander={true}
          showExpandableButton={true}
        />
        <p>{card.info}</p>
      </Card>
    );
  });
{
   return (
   <div className="card-list">
     {cardList}
     </div>
     );
    }
}
```

And here is the main page:

```
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "react";
import {CardComponent} from "../Components/CardsComponent";
import {DropdownMenu} from "../Components/DropdownComponent";
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function Dashboard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static" style={{ backgroundColor: "#182b36" }}>
          <Toolbar variant="dense">
            <DropdownMenu />
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
              Dashboard
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
      <CardComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `import {CardComponent} from "../Components/CardsComponent";`
Use `import CardComponent from "../Components/CardsComponent";`

You are using `export default` and not named exports in CardComponent.js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: It worked! weirdly enough, i used to have it like you said, but a fix said to try with {}, at least it works now, thanks!